# How to convert row to column in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table as the following :

Original Table

[image]

I need help to write a access query to append the Report Date into the respective Offered Date, Confirmation Date and Arrived Date based on the Booking ID. The output looks like this

Desired Output

[image]

Comment: And http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ ?

Comment: What you should be searching for is called "pivot", combined with keyword "ms access". Example search result: [Create PivotTable or PivotChart views in an Access desktop database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-views-in-an-Access-desktop-database-83e524df-dfbd-456d-9dd0-0a48c1aa6752?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: Looks like a simple CROSSTAB query. Use the query wizard to help build.